# Java ScriptEngine and parent window functions

Tags: java, javascript, browser, scriptengine

I am using the Java `ScriptEngine` to call a JS function from a backing bean under certain conditions in the program. The catch is that the JSF page is running in an iFrame. Although the iFrame is not the real problem at this stage, I want it to be able to browse to a new page. For this, I have used `top.window.location` and `parent.location` and they work on a button click to load the page out of the iFrame without a problem.

This is a sample of the code I'm using for this:

```
    ScriptEngine se = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    se.eval("function someFunc(){parent.location = \"www.someurl.com\";}");
    Invocable invocableJS = (Invocable) se;
    invocableJS.invokeFunction("someFunc");
```

With `parent.location` and `top.window.location` I have read that they are called from the browser itsself, and are not **JavaScript**. So because of this, I get the following error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "parent" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
```

It does exactly the same with `document.getElementById("someComponent")` and other similar. And it seems that the error remains with `sun.org.mozilla.....` in **Chrome**, **IE**, and **FF** all together.

**So the question:** How can I get the JS function to possibly use the `parent.location`? I imagine that I would need to check for the browser used and then import or call something from there depending on the browser, but I am not sure how I should go to work to do this. Any light that can possibly be shed on this problem will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your real problem is to control where the link is opened you can just add the appropriate [target-attribute to the anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp), e.g. `target="_top"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem, by checking for the cookies before the redirect in a Javascript method, and simply calling the JS method before the page loads using `onload="someMethod();"` in the body tag. Everything worked out fine, by using the `parent.location` to navigate to the new page. Tested in **FF, Chrome and IE**. Thus there was also no need for the **ScriptEngine** in this situation.